# Template trouble with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

With GCC in Linux, this following code compiles well. But with visual studio, an error C2893 occurs. Do you have any ideas ?

```
struct A
{
};
struct B
{
    typedef A Data;
};
struct C
{
    typedef B Data;
};
template<typename Type>
typename Type::Data::Data  test( Type in)
{
    return Type::Data::Data();
}

int main(){
    C c;
    C::Data::Data a;//works
    test(c);//error C2893: The specialization of the function template 'Type :: Data :: {ctor} test (Type)' failed
}
```

Thanks a lot

Solution by Avakar: because Data::Data refers to the constructor of the type Data, you have to use this idiom:

```
typename identity<typename Type::Data>::type::Data
```

Comment: Are we supposed to have memorized all VS error codes? Please be so kind as to reproduce the error message in your question.

Comment: Isn't the problem that empty structs are a GNU extension? (Btw who cares about VS, seriously?)

Comment: @H2CO3, empty structs are allowed in plain C++, and I do, thank you very much.

Comment: @avakar Didn't know that, thanks for the info. (I mean empty structs, not VS.)

Comment: What's `A` and `B` in there for, anyway?

Comment: "What's A and B in there for," It is a study case to focus on the error.

Comment: @Vincent, my point is that the types are not mentioned anywhere in the code and can be removed.

Comment: I make a mistake. The associated type in the typedef of the struct C is B.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler failed to specialize a function template. There can be many causes for this error. In general, the way to resolve a C2893 error is to review the function's signature and make sure you can instantiate every type.